# How to accept date up to one months from today?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have successfully  implemented to reject the date time from past. Now I want to accept the date up to one months, i.e 30 days only from today. How can I achieve it in C#? Following code accepts the date of future only.

```
public class FutureDate : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            DateTime dateTime;
            var isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(Convert.ToString(value),
                "d MMM yyyy",
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.None,
                out dateTime
            );
            return (isValid && dateTime > DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `&& dateTime <= DateTime.AddDays(30)` (or `AddMonths(1)`)

Comment: Thanks Stephen. It's actually DateTime.Now.AddDays(30). Thank you!

Comment: Add a month instead of a fixed number of days, that will handle all the cases better. Also, this will only work with maximum precision if you're not worried about timezones at all :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.

```
return (isValid && dateTime > DateTime.Now && dateTime <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(30));
```

Comment: but what about **February** and that's month which has 31 days.

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman Good question. There is a method **DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)** for such cases.